# How to solve and plot a nonlinear differential equation system?

Tags: matlab, plot, ode, differential-equations, nonlinear-functions

I have a nonlinear system whose time domain response I want to find according to the initial conditions, and plot that in MATLAB, but I don't know how.

My system is

```
d/  ⌈x⌉ _ ⌈-x+y*x^2 ⌉
/dt ⌊y⌋ ‾ ⌊   -y    ⌋
```

The initial condition, `[x0;y0]`, is `[2;1]`.

Regards,

Comment: I would start by reading the documentation of [`ode45`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html).

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem using the ode45 function. For example I would write in a file called Main.m:

```
close all
[tcont,Xcont]=ode45(@eqStac,[0 2.5],[2 ;1],[]);
plot(tcont,Xcont(:,1),'*r');
hold on
plot(tcont,Xcont(:,2),'*');
```

and then I have to create a function computing your system in the file eqStac.m:

```
function xpoint=eqStac(t,x)
xpoint(1)=-x(1)+x(2)*x(1)^2;
xpoint(2)=-x(2);
xpoint=xpoint(:);
end
```

In the end you would have this plot:

x in red and y in blue:
[image: x in red and y in blue]

I remarked that your system is diverging at about 4.8 seconds.